# Are all transactions in mempool issued by an EOA?

Tags: pending-transactions, txpool, eoa

I wrote some code that gets pending txns contract code on Ethereum, and all i get is contract code: `0x` which means no contract code thus txn is issued by an EOA.

Can we assume that every txn in mempool is issued by an EOA? simply because a contract account can't initiate a txn, what am I missing here?